# How I can copy xml file from the isolatedstoragefile

Tags: xml, xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am working on the `isolatedstoragefile`  were i need to copy the xml file from the  `isolatedstoragefile` and then i need to read the xml file.

I am getting an error in the line `myIsolatedStorage.CopyFile();` where it needs a path for the xml file which is in my common folder.  After setting the path it is throwing another exception

> it is not permitted

The code:

```
private async void CopyDatabase()
{
    bool isDatabaseExisting = false;

    try
    {
        StorageFolder InstallationFolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Common");
        StorageFile file = await InstallationFolder.GetFileAsync("Notification.txt");
        IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        myIsolatedStorage.CopyFile("Notification.txt","Notification.txt",bool "abc.txt");

        IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        isDatabaseExisting = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        isDatabaseExisting = false;
    }

    if (!isDatabaseExisting)
    {
        StorageFolder InstallationFolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Common");
        StorageFile file = await InstallationFolder.GetFileAsync("Notification.xml");
        IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        myIsolatedStorage.CopyFile(file.DisplayName, file.DisplayName);
    }
}
```

Comment: does your app folder cotain the common folder?

Comment: yes  in my project which contain the MainPage.Xaml  there is by default a Common folder in which i placed my notification.txt file

Comment: Is your 'build action' set to 'content' and 'copy to output directory' to 'copy always' or 'copy if newer'?

Comment: Just try this snippet
     
StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    
// Create a new folder name DataFolder.
    
var dataFolder = await local.CreateFolderAsync("DataFolder",
        CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

instead of using Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Common");